# How to call a variable with a value calculated from one method in another method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, call

My code does a calculation upon a button press in "IBAction" and returns the result in a string as the "message" in "UIAlertView".

```
    else{

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You require an average GPA of at least %.2f to achieve your Goal of %@", gpagoal, (NSString *)[myPickerDelegate.myGoal objectAtIndex: [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]]; 

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nothing is Impossible" 
                                                    message:str 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Good Luck" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Tweet",nil];

    //show alert
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    NSLog(@"All Valid");
}
```

i have a problem of how to pull the "gpagoal" value from the calculation's "IBAction" method.

below is the code for the standalone button for tweeting, which works if i am able to port over the gpagoal value from the other method.

```
- (IBAction)sendEasyTweet:(id)sender {
// Set up the built-in twitter composition view controller.
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

// i have problem trying to pull the result "gpagoal" from the calculation's "IBAction" method as i dunno how to pull out variable from a method to another method.
NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"I need an average GPA of at least %.2f this semester to achieve my Goal of %@", gpagoal, (NSString *)[myPickerDelegate.myGoal objectAtIndex: [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]]; 

// Set the initial tweet text. See the framework for additional properties that can be set.
[tweetViewController setInitialText:str2];

// Create the completion handler block.
[tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    //NSString *output;

    switch (result) {
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            // The cancel button was tapped.
            //output = @"Tweet cancelled.";
            NSLog(@"Tweet cancelled");
            break;
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            // The tweet was sent.
            //output = @"Tweet done.";
            NSLog(@"Tweet done");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Dismiss the tweet composition view controller.
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];

// Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
[self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need a variable that is available throughout your class

```
// ViewController.h

...
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
   double gpagoal;
}
```

Make sure it is properly initialized and updated as needed.

Comment: i actually tried the above mentioned of adding "double gpagoal" to the interface of the view controller before. then i got a warning - local declaration of 'gpagoal' hides instance variable. after reading your answer, i think the reason i got the warning is because i didn't initialize the variable. so how should i initialize it and update the variable? thanks.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` set `pgagoal = 1.0;`. Whenever the controller gets info from the view or model that `pgagoal` has changed, set `gpagoal` to the new value.

Comment: okay viewdidload, what should i type? 

    GPAMainViewController *gpagoal = 0; ?

Comment: Please read my comment. I gave you the whole line. A double is not a pointer so please get rid of the star.

Comment: Sweet, it works! so i declare a new global variable call pgagoal in the interface of view controller.h and then i set it in viewdidload to equals 1.0. then when gpagoal value changes, i set pgagoal = gpagoal to transfer the new value to it. when i wanna use the value(gpagoal) in other method, i call the global variable pgagoal. this solves the side problem thanks a lot! do you have the solution of getting the othertitlebutton to send a tweet?

Comment: sorry mundi i think u edited the post and i posted the reply to your pre-edited post as my page wasn't refresh. thus i sounded silly.

Comment: You should accept the answer and make a new question with your Twitter problem.

Comment: i have edited the question and accepted your answer. thanks Mundi for sharing your knowledge =)